# Yii2 Отбор из подкатегорий

Tags: php, yii2

Вообщем есть категория в которой находятся товары и другие подкатегории и мне надо как-то вывести все товары, которые находятся в этой категории и во всех подкатегориях, проблема в вот что из-за прикрученой постраничной навигации я не могу работать с массивами, а как работать с объектами я хз, поэтому прошу помощи.
Ну и то что у меня на данный момент в коде:

```
$categorys = Category::find()->andWhere(['parent_id' => $category->id])->orderBy('name')->all();
for ($i = 0; $i < $categorys; $i++) {
        ??
    }
$adverts_category_all = Advert::find()->with('user')->where(['category_id' => $category->id, 'city' => $_SESSION['city'], 'type' => 'active', 'adv_active' => 'active'])->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC]);
    // подключаем класс Pagination, выводим по 5 пунктов на страницу
    $pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $adverts_category_all->count(), 'pageSize' => 5, 'forcePageParam' => false, 'pageSizeParam' => false]);
    // приводим параметры в ссылке к ЧПУ
    $adverts_category = $adverts_category_all->offset($pages->offset)->limit($pages->limit)->all();
return $this->render('view', compact('adverts_category', 'pages', 'categorys'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел я решение своей проблемы, спасибо что Yii2 умеет отбирать из бд даже если переменная является массивом. Вот код вдруг кому поможет:

```
$categorys_id[] = $category->id;
    foreach ($categorys as $cat_id) {
        $categorys_id[] = $cat_id->id;
    }

    $adverts_category_all = Advert::find()->with('user')->where(['category_id' => $categorys_id, 'city' => $_SESSION['city'], 'type' => 'active', 'adv_active' => 'active'])->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC]);
```